# Astatic DN-HZ microphone

Tags: old, microphone, equipment

I have recently inherited an Astatic DN-HZ mic, it's on a stand with a grip trigger. It was used for a PA system back in the 50's. The frequency response on is pretty narrow, not a lot of low end, doesn't seem like much under 110. Is this thing worth anything? It kinda gives a cool stylized sound, I'll probably hang on to it, just wondering more about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep it.

Microphones are like colors on a painter's palette or lenses to a photographer,

No two mics are the same and if this one gives a particular sound, learn it well and make a mental note of what it sounds like and what it can do and it can come in very handy one day when you're recording something that might fit perfectly with it.

I'd be interested in using it as a radio futzer or a TV speaker worldizing mic.

Might sound great on guitar cabinets.

Comment: cool, thanks. Yeah I think my foley artist is going to have fun with it. 

Answer (score 1):

don't plug that thing into a D50.  I got one and it killed mine.